# Clarification of ambiguity in qt() signature in R

Tags: r, quantiles, t-distribution

My understanding of qt() is that it takes a confidence percentage and a degrees-of-freedom, and returns a distance from the mean.

I've seen multiple examples from both books and websites that pass a 0.975 as the first parameter:

```
qt(0.975, 8)
```

...while stating that it's being used to derive the confidence-interval for 95%.

What sense does that make? Should I assume that this is some simple, but pervasive, error, and that they meant to pass 0.95? Or, is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: they're looking for a 2-tailed 95% confidence interval, so the mass in either tail is 1-0.975=0.025.

Comment: In other words, 1 - (0.025 + 0.025) = 0.95.

Comment: @BenBolker I'm new to this whole thing.. Does the default confidence-interval calculation already account for one of the tails, such that they just have to compensate by one to achieve two?

Comment: @BenBolker I'm asking why, if the mass of a single tail is 2.5% and they're looking for a two-tailed CI, why the CI has only been increased by the amount of a single tail. I'm asking from the perspective of a pedantic ("take it literally") engineer.

Comment: This is the wrong forum to pose questions to fill in gaps in your statistical education.

Comment: @BondedDust It's very difficult for me to frame the questions, because I'm not familiar with the language, and we're already familiar with the context of the question, here. I thought it'd just be one more comment to close the idea for me. Posted: http://bit.ly/1uEs2Ug